# Cortar lineas de un archivo y pegarlos a otro en java

Tags: java

El problema es el siguiente, el usuario selecciona un archivo con N cantidad de lineas y selecciona un limite de lineas, es decir si el archivo seleccionado tiene 100 lineas y el limite de lineas de 10 el programa debe crear 10 archivos con 10 lineas.

```
  public static void Seleccionar(int num, JTextField txtLimite) throws IOException{ 

    int cont = 0;
    String s1;
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int valor = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);

    if (valor == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String ruta = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

   File f = new File(ruta);
   //Se escanea las lineas del archivo seleccionado
  BufferedReader entrada1 = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (f));                 
  FileWriter writer = null;
      try {
          //Creamos el archivo y escribimos en el
          cont++;         
              File file = new File("probando"+cont+".txt");
          writer = new FileWriter(file);
          for (int j = 0; j < num ; j++) {
               s1 = entrada1.readLine();
              writer.write(s1+"|");          
          }    
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(PruebaEscritura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } finally {
          try {
              writer.close();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(PruebaEscritura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
      }  
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fileChooser, "No sea seleccionado ningun fichero");
    }
}
```

el programa crea el primer archivo y guarda las 10 primeras lineas, pero no continua.

lo que estoy buscando es algo como esto:

```
inicio
ingresar limite de lineas  
10
selecciona el archivo que deseas segmentar
probando.txt


///Procesando///

se escanea el archivo
cantidad de lineas 100
se toma la primera linea
se crea el archivo probando1.txt
se pega la primera linea
se toma la segunda linea
se pega la segunda linea
...
se toma la decima linea
se pega la decima linea
se crea el archivo probando2.txt
se toma la linea 11
se pega la linea 11
...
se toma la linea 20
se pega la linea 20
...
se crea el archivo probando10.txt
se toma la linea 91
se pega la linea 91
...
se toma la linea 100
se pega la linea 100

no se encontraron mas lineas
fin
```

Comment: Es que tu programa tal cual está no tiene sentido. Lees una línea y te metes en un bucle `for` a escribir esa misma linea tantas veces como `num`, la misma línea, porque no vuelves a leer. otra línea Prueba a depurar y verás cómo va el flujo. El programa es muy sencillo: abres el fichero y lees línea a línea y las vas escribiendo en otro hasta que lleves tantas como diga `num`, entonces cierras el fichero donde escribes y empiezas con otro, hasta terminar el original.

Comment: @SuperG280 estoy tratando de reducir el código lo mas que puedo para que puedan entender, dame un momento

Comment: @SuperG280 listo, he reducido un poco el codigo y especifique lo que deseo resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Faltaba colocar el `while` de `entrada1` y preguntar si `entrada1` ha detectado una linea

```
 int cont = 0;
            String s1;
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int valor = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);

            if (valor == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                String ruta = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

           File f = new File(ruta);
           //Se escanea las lineas del archivo seleccionado
          BufferedReader entrada1 = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (f));                 
          FileWriter writer = null;

            while (entrada1.ready()) {         

                     try {
                  //Creamos el archivo y escribimos en el
                  cont++;             
                  File file = new File("probando"+cont+".txt");
                  writer = new FileWriter(file);
                  for (int j = 0; j < num ; j++) {
                      if (entrada1.ready()==true) {
                       s1 = entrada1.readLine();  
                          writer.write(s1+"\n");  
                      }

                  }  
              } catch (IOException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(PruebaEscritura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              } finally {
                  try {
                      writer.close();
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                      Logger.getLogger(PruebaEscritura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  }
                }

               }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(txtLimite, "Proceso finalizado");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fileChooser, "No sea seleccionado ningun fichero");
        }
```

Comment: Y con esto ya te funciona como querías? Una recomendación: cuando estás leyendo lineas y guardándolas en el fichero, en el for, compruebas que entrada1 aun tenga datos para escribir en el otro fichero. Si ya no quedan líneas, aun sigues dando vueltas en el for para nada. En ese caso habrías terminado y tendrías que salir del bucle.